# R Highcharter - Countries displayed incorrectly on hcmap

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to use `hcmap` from `highcharter` to create a world map to show different values from some countries. Below is an example:

```
library(highcharter)

df = read.table(text="
country, value
au, 0.125
cn, 0.263
in, 0.223
jp, 0.191
kr, 0.215
my, 0.088
ph, 0.197
id, 0.210
th, 0.217,
nz, 0.115", header=T)

hcmap(map ="custom/world-highres2.js", data = df, value = "value")
```

[image]

There are several issues with the map:

1. Most of the countries are not correctly displayed. For example, Australia `au` did not show up. In addition, some countries got messed up. For example, US was not in the data set. The US value on the map actually belonged to India, and India's value was from Malaysia. I got the country codes (`au`,`cn`,`in`, etc.) from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zfxs5ah2/).
2. Countries are shown as black and the blue scale bar at the bottom does not show any values. The left side of it should have the minimum value and the right side should have the maximum value. I'd like to change the color to red for both countries and the bar.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [jsfiddle example](http://Data%20is%20joined%20to%20map%20using%20value%20of%20'hc-key'%20property%20by%20default.) you referred to there is a comment at the beginning that

> Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.

so I changed the country column name to `hc-key` and it magically worked. Strangely, setting `joinBy` argument to `"country"` doesn't help.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
  ~`hc-key`, ~value,
  "au", 0.125,
  "cn", 0.263,
  "in", 0.223,
  "jp", 0.191,
  "kr", 0.215,
  "my", 0.088,
  "ph", 0.197,
  "id", 0.210,
  "th", 0.217,
  "nz", 0.115
)

library(highcharter)
hcmap(map ="custom/world-highres2.js", data = df, joinBy = "hc-key", value = "value")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @laroslav!! Indeed, I also tried to set `joinBy` to different properties but had no luck. Is there a way to change the color from blue to red?

Comment: @T-T I don't have a quick answer tbh. Setting `color = "red"` inside `hcmap` doesn't work obviously. It would make sense to post it as a separate question.

Comment: I got it! Using the `hc_colorAxis` along with `RColorBrewer` package does the job! `hcmap(map ="custom/world-highres2.js", data = df, joinBy = "hc-key", value = "value") %>%hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")[9],maxColor = brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")[3])`. Thanks so much!